# How to add letters to string in hangman. the "wrong" section

Tags: bluej

```
System.out.println("Word: " + t);
System.out.println("Guesses: " + guess + bad);
```

i have a string "bad" and its just an empty string. How do i add the guesses to the string so the string bad remembers what letters are guessed and displays them? im writing in bluej by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder. Whenever a guess is made, append to the end of the StringBuilder.
You will want to look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html